# How to print infopath form for document library?

Tags: infopath, printing

I have created one InfoPath form with two views and published it into the document library.
I want to have a print button on the form so that I can print the document.

How to achieve it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sharepoint 2010 - Printing Infopath List Form](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/53094/sharepoint-2010-printing-infopath-list-form)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the below steps,

**Procedure**

The following is the procedure to create a Print button. We are using HTML and JavaScript for the solution.

**Step 1:** Enable Modeless forms

By default the view/edit forms are opened as dialog (modal) forms. We need to change this to edit the page.

Choose "List" > "List Settings" > "Advanced Settings"

Set the last option to No.

Now you can see the View form is opened in full page mode.

**Step 2:** Edit Page

Open a list item in View Form, choose the "Site Actions" > "Edit Page" option to bring the page to edit mode. Add a Content Editor Web part and enter the following HTML contents.

Click OK to save the changes. Choose Stop Editing from the page tab.

We added a Print button that will invoke the window.print() method on click.

Step 3: Test the page

Refresh the list and open a list item in View Page. Click on the Print button

Step 4: Enable back dialog

Now we need to re-enable the dialog form. Go to "List Settings" > "Advanced Settings" and enable the "Dialog" option.

**Or** You can use [WireBear InfoPath Printer.](http://infopathprinter.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I want print button on the ribbon.

Comment: My clients want all codeless solution.